# useEffect hook called multiple times when dependency value remains the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out why my `useEffect` hook keeps getting called multiple times, even when the dependency has the same value. I'm using the following code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Cards from '../../../cards/Cards'
import UserCard from '../../../cards/users/Card'
import LoadingContainer from '../../../LoadingContainer'
import UsersResource from '../../../../api/resources/Users'

const Users = ({ users }) => (
  <Cards>
    {users.map((user) => (
      <UserCard user={user} key={`user-${user.id}`} />
    ))}
  </Cards>
)

const UsersPage = () => {
  const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(true)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [initialUsers, setInitialUsers] = useState([])
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await UsersResource.getIndex()
    setInitialUsers(response.data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('users changed:', users)
    initialLoad ? setInitialLoad(false) : setLoading(false)
  }, [users])

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(initialUsers)
  }, [initialUsers])

  return (
    <LoadingContainer
      loading={loading}
      hasContent={!!users.length}
    >
      <Users users={users} />
    </LoadingContainer>
  )
}

Users.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape).isRequired,
}

export default UsersPage
```

This is the effect that gets re-run when the value of the users dependency stays the same:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('users changed:', users)
  initialLoad ? setInitialLoad(false) : setLoading(false)
}, [users])
```

Here's the output:

```
users changed: []
users changed: []
users changed: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So `users` is obviously being recognized as changed twice, even though both times the effect is called, it returns the same value. This results in my `loading` state being set to `false` before the request finishes.

It only runs once if I change the initial state assignment of `users` from this...

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
```

To this...

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState(initialUsers)
```

This tells me that the component must be rerendering simply because `users` is pointing to `initialUsers` in the second effect, instead of just a blank array (even though `initialUsers` returns a blank array as well). Can anyone explain why this happens this way? I can't seem to find any documentation describing this behavior (maybe I'm blind).

I would expect the value to be the only thing to influence an effect, but it seems like it might get triggered because the dependency is pointing to a new reference in memory. Am I off?

Comment: Are you by chance using `<StrictMode>`? Strict mode deliberately simulates unmounting/remounting the component, so the effect will run twice at the start. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: @NicholasTower No. If you read my explanation at the bottom, you'll notice that I mentioned that changing the initial value of users fixes it. So StrictMode isn't relevant.

Comment: I agree with Nicholas, this seems related to `React.StrictMode` component behavior. If you disagree can you provide a [mcve]? Why do you have two loading states and two users states? It seems redundant.

Comment: @DrewReese it's not related to StrictMode. Aside from having it disabled, I've stated in the post that it only hits once when I initialize `users` with `initialUsers` instead of an empty array, and I even reiterated that in this comment thread. So I'm not sure what kind of merit StrictMode could possibly still have. I'm using different loading/user states because I have a filter on the same component that fetches and changes users via user interaction. I took that out for this post to keep it as simple as possible. Here's a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-thunder-bcl2ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bit of a misunderstanding between value equality and reference equality. React uses reference equality.

The initial `initialUsers` and `users` state values are `[]`, and on the initial render cycle there is a `useEffect` hook that enqueues an update to `users` with the current `initialUsers` value.

Note that `initialUsers` isn't ***not*** the same reference as `users`, so `initialUsers === users` evaluates false.

```js
const initialUsers = [];
const users = [];

console.log(initialUsers === users); // false
```

Note also that `[] === []` is also never true since they are two object references.

```js
console.log([] === []); // false
```

This is *roughly* how the logic flows:

1. On the initial render cycle the initial `users` state `[]` is logged in the second `useEffect` hook.
2. The `useEffect` with dependency on `initialUsers` runs and updates the `users` state to the value of the `initialUsers` state. `[]` (*but a different reference*).
3. The second `useEffect` hook logs the `users` state update, again `[]`.
4. The `fetchUsers` handler has fetched data and enqueues an update to the `initialUsers` state.
5. The second `useEffect` hook logs the `users` state update, now a populated array.

Code:

```
const fetchUsers = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

  // (4) update initialUsers
  setInitialUsers(response.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchUsers();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // (1) initial render, first log "[]"
  // (3) second render, second log "[]"
  // (5) third render, third log "[.........]"
  console.log("users changed:", users);
  initialLoad ? setInitialLoad(false) : setLoading(false);
}, [users]);

useEffect(() => {
  // (2) initial render update users
  setUsers(initialUsers);
}, [initialUsers]);
```

The difference when you initialize the `users` state to the `initialState` value is now they are the same reference.

```js
const initialUsers = [];
const users = initialUsers;

console.log(initialUsers === users); // true
```

This subtle difference skips the enqueued update #2 above since `users` and `initialUsers` are already the same reference.

Comment: Ah, yes. This makes sense, thanks for the thorough explanation. I suspected it might be due to inequalities between dependency references. All this time I thought dependency values always depended on the ending evaluations (empty array in this case), but since arrays are references rather than primitive data types, two different arrays will never equate. To confirm I'm not completely crazy, I changed all the values to numbers instead of arrays in the sample (keeping all variable names the same) and the behavior is different. There's only one initial render when using numbers instead of arrays.

Comment: @Doug Welcome, glad the explanation got through and still made sense. Yes, the subtle nuances of Javascript equality mixed with React's Reconciliation process. Cheers and good luck!